# Extracting a Currency Ticker from Tweet Text using Polars

Tags: python-polars

First question so will try my best to follow guidelines.

I am attempting a data analysis project. I have a dateframe with 3 columns like below - Date, User, Tweet. The date is the timestamp of the tweet, user is the @handle of who tweeted, and the tweet is the text of the tweet.

| Date | User | Tweet |
| --- | --- | --- |

An example tweet is the following:
"$PHB will easily reach 1.5$ as it did many times, the better your entry, the bigger the profits."

This is in the dataframe, along with the user and the timestamp.

**What I'm Trying to Do**

- I want to go through the entire column of tweets, and if there is a ticker in the tweet (e.g $btc, $PHB), then add this ticker into a 4th column called Tickers.

I have tried the following code lines in Python:

`df = df.with_columns([pl.col("Tweet").str.extract(r'\$.*').alias('Tickers')])`

`df = df.with_columns([pl.col("Tweet").str.extract_regex(r'\$[A-Za-z0-9]+').alias('Tickers')])`

I was expecting this regex expression to extract the ticker and insert it into a 4th, column but instead the output is as follows:

| Date | User | Tweet | Tickers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.6781e6 | ganymede_0x | $LQTY | null |
| ---------- | ----------- | ---------------------- | -------- |
| 1.6781e6 | ganymede_0x | $DF chart looks ready. | null |
| ---------- | ----------- | ---------------------- | -------- |
| 1.6781e6 | ganymede_0x | Bought $LQTY. | null |
| ---------- | ----------- | ---------------------- | -------- |

Clearly there is a ticker in the tweet, but it is returning null.

Here is my full code to get to this point:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.read_csv('shilling.csv')

df = df.select('Date', 'User', 'Tweet')

df = df.filter(pl.col("Tweet").apply(lambda x: any(w.startswith("$") for w in x.split())))

# convert Date column to datetime type
df = df.with_columns([pl.col('Date').str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")])

# convert Date column to timestamp (int type)
df = df.with_columns([df['Date'].cast(int)])
df = df.with_columns([df['Date'] / 1000000000])

df = df.with_columns([pl.col("Tweet").str.extract(r'\$.*').alias('Tickers')])

#df = df.with_columns([pl.col("Tweet").str.extract_regex(r'\$[A-Za-z0-9]+').alias('Tickers')])

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's nice if you also provide your example as runnable code e.g.

```
import io
import polars as pl

csv = """
Date,User,Tweet,Tickers
1.6781e6,ganymede_0x,$LQTY
1.6781e6,ganymede_0x,$DF chart looks ready.
1.6781e6,ganymede_0x,Bought $LQTY.
"""

df = pl.read_csv(csv.encode())
```

[`.extract`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.extract.html#polars.Expr.str.extract) returns the content of capture groups - so you need `()` in your pattern.

```
>>> df.with_columns(Tickers = pl.col("Tweet").str.extract(r"([$][A-Za-z0-9]+)"))
shape: (3, 4)
┌──────────┬─────────────┬────────────────────────┬─────────┐
│ Date     ┆ User        ┆ Tweet                  ┆ Tickers │
│ ---      ┆ ---         ┆ ---                    ┆ ---     │
│ f64      ┆ str         ┆ str                    ┆ str     │
╞══════════╪═════════════╪════════════════════════╪═════════╡
│ 1.6781e6 ┆ ganymede_0x ┆ $LQTY                  ┆ $LQTY   │
│ 1.6781e6 ┆ ganymede_0x ┆ $DF chart looks ready. ┆ $DF     │
│ 1.6781e6 ┆ ganymede_0x ┆ Bought $LQTY.          ┆ $LQTY   │
└──────────┴─────────────┴────────────────────────┴─────────┘
```

I'm using `[$]` instead of `\$` here as a preference - it's not required.

Your `.filter()` can also be improved by using `.str.contains` instead:

```
df.filter(pl.col("Tweet").str.contains(r"(^|\s)[$]"))
```

`.apply()` is "slow" and should be considered as a "last resort."

Comment: Thank you very much - this works perfectly now. Going forward I will provide actual examples of runnable code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one ticker in tweet, use `.str.extract_all`

```py
df.with_columns(
    Tickers = pl.col("Tweet").str.extract_all(r'\$\w+')
)
```